# Call remote stored procedure to return table efficiently

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an SSIS import process where I need to deduplicate a contact record against the target CRM contact table via linked server.

Currently I have created a local scalar function which does the job but it's highly inefficient. I pass in the relevant criteria - firstname, lastname, postcode, email etc - from the import file and the local function using synonyms pointing to CRM tables via linked server, perform some complex logic to determine if the contact is a match and if so return the relevant `contactid`. It does this per row in import - could be 10 records or 10000 records.

I am thinking the best way forward is to create a stored procedure on the CRM target database and pass in a table of relevant contact values from import and perform complex logic locally and return results locally.

I haven't done it as yet but I understand I can pass in a table of values to a stored procedure but as we are not going to have a linked server from CRM back to local, what is the best way to return the multiple results? Using SQL Server 2012; I could use SQL Server 2014 if necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: having the SP local to the CRM should reduce the lag greatly!  One way I often do this is to pass XML (as VARCHAR) with the data I want to work with.  Call the SP from your ETL server and have the SP return a status variable when complete.  If you need to pass data back you could again use XML or you could have a staging location on the CRM server that your Linked Server knows where to query from.

Comment: Have you considered using the [Lookup Transformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?  This can pipe matched/non-matched records to separate locations.

Comment: I think i might have to create a table at target as Matt suggests. Can't use lookup transformation as i am not doing a lookup per se, rather using values in source file to determine if a record match is found based on complex logic, ie if lastname matches & email matches & title matches then found but if title matches & email matches but lastname doesn't match then try matching on firstname and so on.